# Error when getting "Suggestions" from ShardedDocumentStore: "You cannot get database commands for this query"

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

I recently started using a sharded document store in my project.  Going back through some old functionality that was working I am now getting an error.  Wondering if getting suggestions across a sharded data store is not supported yet?  Getting error "You cannot get database commands for this query" when calling "Suggest".  Not sure what else to try at this point.

```
        using (var session = Store.OpenSession())
        {

                var query = session.Query<Item>("ItemIndex").Statistics(out stats)
                    .Search(x => x.Title, searchCriteria.Title)
                    .Where(x => x.ItemZip.In(zipcodes))
                    .Skip(pageNumber * 40)
                    .Take(40); // Take posts in the page size

                toReturn = query.ToList();

                if (toReturn.Count() == 0)
                {
                    var results = query.Suggest(new SuggestionQuery()//<---- error here
                                        {
                                            Field = "Title",
                                            Term = searchCriteria.Title,
                                            MaxSuggestions = 1,
                                            Accuracy = 0.4f,
                                            Popularity = true,
                                        }).Suggestions;
                    if (results.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        searchCriteria.AlternateSearch = results[0];
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google groups response from Oren.  "...it isn't supported currently"

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/ksJcQD1OJqE